# Why the linear-gradient should be repeat-x when hover a button?

Tags: css

My code is at https://codepen.io/xflotus/pen/gzWyrg. The button is setted with a linear-gradient background like this:

```html
background-color: #0cf;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0cf, #069);
background-image: linear-gradient(top, #0cf, #069);
```

. When hover the button, the background is to move down 10px.

```html
background-position: 0 10px;
```

But there is a gray bar that is not good. So, the

```html
background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

is added. I think the background image should be repeate-y because it is linear-gradient vertically and the gary bar is due to moving down it. So, why?

Comment: I don't see any grey bar get added when I either hover over or click on the buttons. What **exactly** is not working the way you would like it to?

Comment: remove the background-repeat: repeat-x; can get it.

Comment: in the following rule:

Comment: .button:hover {
   background-position: 0 10px;
   background-repeat: repeat-x;
  }

Comment: what is the output you are expecting?

Comment: With using the 'background-repeat: repeat-x;' , the result is correct. I just wonder why it is wrong to use repeat-y or repeat.